# Place to purchase decent used servers?

Tags: hardware

We're in the market for 10 or so servers and everything we're finding on ebay is either too slow or scsi and we want sata. Are there some goods sites to find deals on used servers?

Comment: Anywhere in the world?

Answer (score 3):

I have a Customer who has purchased several off-lease Dell servers from Stollard Technologies (http://www.stikc.com/) to great success. Stollard offers warranty and accessories. The last batch of machines we got, five (5) PowerEdge 2850's, were all in excellent shape (clean, slight scratches but no dents or dings), and had no operational defects whatsoever. I was very pleased.

If you want to get a group of like-hardware machines, companies like Stollard are the way to go. I just happen to like them because I have personal experience.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try [Dell Outlet](http://www.dell.com/us/en/dfb/enterprise/servers/ct.aspx?refid=servers&s=dfb&cs=28) for newish servers or search the Google for "used servers" and "off lease" to find ~ 3 yr old servers.

Comment: We buy everything exclusively from the Dell Outlet.  They often have tremendous deals and offer the same (or better) warranties on all Outlet products.  If you're searching for a good deal, I'd recommend looking at the "Scratch and Dent" listings.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck finding Servers, Racks, and other equipment on CraigsList.

Some really good deals to be had.  Especially if you are looking for Server Racks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very well-known site, but my company auctions items here and, because of the limited exposure of the site, the buyer always gets great deals on everything from servers to cell phones to vehicles to tools.

http://www.publicsurplus.com/

Select a (region)state and (agency)city or organization close to you and be sure to check back frequently.  We only auction once per month, but some organizations auction more/less frequently.

We just had 5 24-port stackmaster managed switches go for $30...for all 5.  Also, I have seen fairly decent servers go for $75 bucks.

Comment: Seriously fun site.

Answer (score 0):

Most cities will have outfits that buy and sell secondhand computer equipment.  Search around your locale to see if you can find one.

Most servers will use SCSI or SAS; servers with SATA disks are something of a niche item, so there may or may not be equipment of this sort available at a given point in time.  If you just want system disks then stick with the SCSI ones that come with the server.  If you need large volumes of SATA data storage you could possibly buy an external array.  Alternatively, you can get secondhand SCSI disk arrays such as a HP MSA30 quite cheaply.

Also, many of the larger outfits that maintain shops on ebay also deal direct.  You could try contacting some of them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had really good luck with purchasing Dell servers on Ebay.  Just look for resellers with high ratings and sales, read the listing very carefully, and review their return policy.  I've bought 15-20 servers, all in almost new condition, for 25-60% of Dell retail price.